# NextJS - How to login user on custom server after Google oAuth login?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to login user on the custom server by Google access token:

Google OAuth success response:

```
provider: 'google',
  type: 'oauth',
  providerAccountId: '1155997xxxxxx',
  access_token: 'ya29.a0Aa4xrXMKQ9xxxxxxx',
  expires_at: 1665739074,
```

I want to send Google's `access_token` as payload to the custom server and login user.

```
async signIn({ account, profile }) {
            if (account.provider === "google") {
                console.log("google", account)
                // return profile.email_verified && profile.email.endsWith("@example.com")
            }
            return true
        },
```

Same process as `CredentialsProvider` in the `sync authorize` part?

Any idea? :)